# Trying to load Python dataframe into Hadoop (Impala) using `ibis`, getting "AttributeError: module 'ibis' has no attribute 'impala' "

Tags: python, jupyter, ibis

I'm running the following block of Python commands in a Jupyter notebook to upload my dataframe, labeled `df`, to Impala:

```
import hdfs
from hdfs.ext.kerberos import KerberosClient
import pandas as pd
import ibis
hdfs = KerberosClient('< URL address >')
client = ibis.impala.connect(host="impala.sys.cigna.com", port=25003, timeout=3600, auth_mechanism="GSSAPI", hdfs_client=hdfs)
db=client.database("< database >")
db.create_table("pythonIBISTest", df)
```

. . . but am getting the error message `AttributeError: module 'ibis' has no attribute 'impala'`.

Note: I've already installed the hdfs, ibis, ibis-framework[Kerberos], and impyla modules in the Jupyter terminal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ibis` in PyPI is a different package. Uninstall `ibis` and install only `ibis-framework`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thanks - I think I'm closer to a solution. I uninstalled `ibis`, restarted my kernel, then reran my code. I'm now seeing an error message: `HdfsError: Authentication failure. Check your credentials.`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `pip install ibis-framework[impala]` to get the impala part of ibis

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I spoke with one of my company's programmers & he created a custom Python package that allows us to write table to Impala.